# Is there a precompiled Nextcloud Ubuntu client?

Tags: snap, owncloud-client, nextcloud

[It seems](https://nextcloud.com/install/#install-clients) there's no prepackaged binary client officially available for GNU/Linux (only sources).

Is there an unofficial `.snap`, `.deb`, `.AppImage`? I'm currently stuck on the ownCloud client while connecting to a NextCloud server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also use nextcloud. The nextcloud devs have created a ppa with a precompiled nextcloud client. Here's what you have to do:

```
### Install Nextcloud client
sudo -s
add-apt-repository ppa:nextcloud-devs/client
apt update
apt install nextcloud-client
```

P.S. Currently tested and works in Ubuntu 16.04.2

Answer (score 2):

Found this one:

```
sudo snap install --edge nextcloud-client-kyrofa
```

source [twitter](https://twitter.com/rainveil/status/811312087406284800).

It seems to work, but there seem to be 2 problems: [broken tray icon and keychain](https://twitter.com/rainveil/status/811312612701065216).

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install nextcloud-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

An AppImage bundles an application and everything it needs to run that cannot be assumed to be part of all target systems. Unlike the other solutions mentioned, AppImage does not require special client/runtime infrastructure from the target systems.

I have created an experimental Nextcloud client AppImage and sent a pull request (= code that would produce an AppImage automatically for each version) in the hope that the Nextcloud project will consider making an official AppImage for Linux:

https://github.com/nextcloud/client_theming/pull/29

The Nextcloud project would just need to merge this pull request and then an AppImage would be built automatically for every commit. So if you think this would be useful, be sure to give a "thumbs up" in the linked pull request and comment there, so that the project sees that an AppImage would be appreciated by users.

Comment: I'll certainly do it.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit, there's a pre-compiled deb available [here](https://repo.morph027.de/#nextcloud-client).
That one works very well for me.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, just type:

`sudo snap install nextcloud`

on Ubuntu 16.04 or later (or any distribution shipping `snapd`).

**Edit**: This is the server, not the client.

Comment: `snap find nextcloud` tells me it's `Nextcloud Server`, is the description wrong?

Comment: It's definitely only the server https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap :(